# unable to remove skewness from my data

Tags: normal-distribution, data-transformation, normalization, skewness, skew-normal-distribution

I am trying to remove skewness from my data, since my linear model requires it. e.g. all the columns in my data look like this after plotting a kde:

[image]

my data contains, 0s, posituve and negative values. This is what i would expect, a bowley skewness measure gives 0.4 (a value of 0 means it is symmetrical). Since yeo-johnson does not preserve sign of the data, i use a hyperbolic-sinh transformation. e.g.:

```
asinh_transform = np.arcsinh(fe_fr_status[numeric_columns])
```

i then plot the column above and i get:

[image]

a bowley skew measure on this column is now 0.15, so yes this is better and closer to 0 but still it is not what i want. How else can i go about this? for some columns the skewness goes from 0.9 to 0.7.. so it is still highly skewed. unsure how else to go about this!

Comment: Could you perhaps say what this distribution stands for, i.e. what kind of data are you working on?

Comment: hi yes it is financial data e.g. from financial statements

Comment: You would be better off asking your real problem, probably you don't need to remove skewness, there is no such assumption on the predictor variables. So tell us your real, modeling problem!

Comment: well i am using an xgboost, i did not remove outliers or normalize/transform the data to make it more 'normal' since i do not think you need this assumption for tree based methods. however my results are very poor and am wondering what i can do to the data to make my result better